# MacBook losing charge while shut down

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, battery

I have a Macbook Pro 13 2019 and a Macbook Pro 13 2020.
2019 one runs 10.14.6 Mojave. 2020 one runs latest 10.15 Catalina

When I turn off the Macbook Pro 2020 with "shut down" on 100% and I turn it back on 4-5 days later it's 97%. That's fine-ish.

When I turn off the Macbook Pro 2019 with "shut down" on 100% it loses every day around 8-10% of charge while turned off. 5 days later it was 49%, 2 days later it's 83%, etc.

In system settings wake for wifi and power nap is off.

Any ideas what could be draining the battery while the computer is shut down (not slept) and how to make it not happen?

Comment: When you say "shut down", I assume you're meaning completely turned off and not in sleep or hibernate mode, correct?

Comment: Your battery is no longer holding a charge  it happens.  If you still have that computer under warranty - I would take it in and see if you can get the battery exchanged - it's only a 2019!

Comment: "completely turned off and not in sleep" - yes, I am confirming, correct

Comment: I found that Power Nap was draining my battery, I turned it off and things were better. YMMV.

Comment: Power Nap is off and always was, but thanks

Comment: Same problem here with a new MacBook Pro 13inch 2020 unfortunately. It loses about 3% charge per day when completely shut down. Power Nap is disabled.

Comment: I find it infuriating that I can't guarantee my laptop won't discharge when I've closed the lid.  A number of times now I've been in situations where I've relied on battery power and opened the lid to find up to 40% less power than I left it.  My only solution is to completely shut it down.  Not ideal.

Answer (score 3):

Even if your Macbook isn't drawing power from a battery, the battery itself is chemical in nature and, like all batteries, subject to "[self-discharge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-discharge)". The only time this is an issue is when it's "[elevated self-discharge](https://batteryuniversity.com/index.php/learn/article/elevating_self_discharge)."  So your Macbook needn't be powered-on therefore to suffer some degree of battery drain.

So battery drain in a powered-down state isn't the problem- it happens to all chemical batteries.  Your issue is that it's at an elevated level, which might indicate the battery requires replacement as the 2nd link talks about. Apparently 5% loss within 24 hours and 1-2% per day thereafter is expected for Lithium batteries. Yours is definitely draining at a much higher rate.

If you go to the "***Power***" section of "***System Report***" you can check the status of your battery to see if it's misbehaving ***as mine apparently is in my 2018 Macbook!***:

[image: System Report Battery info]

So assuming you're 100% sure that the affected Macbook isn't in a sleep state, but fully powered down, this looks a lot like a hardware issue regarding the battery. [Here's some guidance from Apple on troubleshooting Battery issues](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204054)

Another thing you can look at for the sake of completeness when reviewing your power issue is [resetting the Service Management Controller (SMC)](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295), if only to exclude this as not being causal before you trundle down to Apple with your Macbook-

Comment: Thanks. Mine saying "Condition: normal" though. Also my gf has a 2017 Macbook Pro with the same issue. Regarding mine the problem is it's a company Macbook, only the 2020 is "mine" and not needed for work. But I may try the Apple Store stuff if I can confirm and it could fit

Comment: My system reports for battery health a Cycle count of 105 and Condition normal, but my battery is draining 100% in 7 days when in hibernation - and I have Power Nap turned off. This is on a late 2016 Mac Pro with Big Sur.